# Upload file with Angular2

Tags: javascript, c#, angular, xmlhttprequest, asp.net-core

I was following a tutorial [here](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2016/02/upload-files-to-node-js-using-angular-2/), on how to upload files with Angular2. However, i when i try implementing the code into my project, the result in my console is just the page html contents instead of the JSON response im suppose to be sending via my POST request on my back end ( asp.net core ). Under the networking tab it seems to  making the POST to the correct address, so i don’t know why I'm getting an html document instead of my response data. Anyone know why?

**upload.html**

```
<h2>Upload</h2>
<input type="file" (change)="fileChangeEvent($event)" placeholder="Upload file..." />
<button type="button" (click)="upload()">Upload</button>
```

**upload.ts**

```
import * as ng from '@angular/core';

@ng.Component({
  selector: 'upload',
  template: require('./upload.html')
})
export class Upload {
    filesToUpload: Array<File>;

    constructor() {
        this.filesToUpload = [];
    }

    upload() {
        this.makeFileRequest("http://localhost:5000/api/SampleData/uploadFile", [], this.filesToUpload).then((result) => {
            console.log(result);
        }, (error) => {
            console.error(error);
        });
    }

    fileChangeEvent(fileInput: any){
        this.filesToUpload = <Array<File>> fileInput.target.files;
    }

    makeFileRequest(url: string, params: Array<string>, files: Array<File>) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            var formData: any = new FormData();
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                formData.append("uploads[]", files[i], files[i].name);
            }
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                    if (xhr.status == 200) {
                        resolve(JSON.parse(xhr.response));
                    } else {
                        reject(xhr.response);
                    }
                }
            }
```

**SampleData.cs**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult uploadFile()
    {
        var files = Request.Form.Files;
        return Json("Working ? ");
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First it looks like your are doing it right from the Angular part, by creating form data. I had some similar issues getting files correctly on a POST request in asp.net. So the way I solved it, is to parse the content from the Request.

First create an empty method, it's important or else will you end up with a 404. Next read the file from the Request object:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult uploadFile()
{
    var files = Request.Files;
    if (Request.Form[0] == null || files[0] == null || files[0].ContentLength < 1)
    {
            // TODO log
            Response.StatusCode = 400;
            return Json("Please provide a file");
    }
    // TODO parse the file(s) as you like :)
    foreach (HttpPostedFile file in files)
    {
        file.SaveAs(file.FileName);
    }
}
```

[Updated for asp.net core]

The changed the Request object in asp.net core, now the form data is in:

```
Request.Form.Files;
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the replay. However im getting a reference error at line var files = Request.Files; .....
'HttpRequest' does not contain a definition for 'Files' and no extension method 'Files' accepting a first argument of type 'HttpRequest' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [netcoreapp1.0]

Comment: Are you using an asp.net controller class?

Comment: Yeah. 
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http; 

namespace Testing.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class SampleDataController : Controller

Comment: Maybe you can access it from: HttpContext.Current.Request.Files

Comment: Oh maybe the issue is, that I am using asp.net MVC

Comment: yeah im using asp.net core. using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpRequest does not contain files.

Comment: Just tried this on a asp.net core project and it works for me: Request.Form.Files;

Comment: What library’s are you using?

Comment: I still get an html document as a response.

Comment: Had to add the XHML headers to get it working. Thanks for the help.           xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option

service.ts

```
uploadDealDocumentFile(document: DealDocument, files: File[]): Observable<any> {
var url = BASE_URL + 'fileupload/';
return Observable.create(observer => {
  let formData: FormData = new FormData(),
    xhr: XMLHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

  for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    //formData.append("selectedDealId", document.dealId);          
    formData.append("uploads[]", files[i], document.dealCode + '-' + files[i].name);
  }

  xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
      if (xhr.status === 200) {
        observer.next(JSON.parse(xhr.response));
        observer.complete();
      } else {
        observer.error(xhr.response);
      }
    }
  };
  xhr.upload.onprogress = (event) => {
    //this.progress = Math.round(event.loaded / event.total * 100);
    //this.progressObserver.next(this.progress);
  };
  xhr.open('POST', url, true);
  xhr.send(formData);
});
}
```

FileUploadController.cs

```
public class FileUploadController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost()]
    public string UploadFiles()
    {
        string sPath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/UploadDocs/");
        int iUploadedCnt = 0;

        HttpFileCollection filesCollection = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files;
        string id = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["Id"];

        for (int i = 0; i <= filesCollection.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            HttpPostedFile file = filesCollection[i];

            if (file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                if (!File.Exists(sPath + Path.GetFileName(file.FileName)))
                {                        
                    file.SaveAs(sPath + Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));
                    iUploadedCnt = iUploadedCnt + 1;
                }
            }
        }

        if (iUploadedCnt > 0)
        {
            return iUploadedCnt + " Files Uploaded Successfully";
        }
        else
        {
            return "Upload Failed";
        }
    }
}
```

Good luck!!

Comment: What is the equivalent of HttpFileCollection for asp.net core?

Comment: Same problem, just returns the http page document. For Node.js it seems to be posting to the server.